# `git log --stat` but with output combining any number of commits?

Tags: git

I want to be able to run `git log -10 --stat ...` and get the regular `git log --stat` output, but for all `10` of the latest commits combined.

(Note that this isn't about 'diff combining' for merge commits.)

Comment: I could have misunderstood what you actually need, but what is wrong with `git diff --stat HEAD~10..HEAD`?

Comment: All commits are full snapshots of all files, so when `git log --stat` shows you the stats of commit P vs commit C (parent vs child), it has run `git diff --stat P C`. If you want stats from comparing arbitrary commit X with arbitrary commit Y, then indeed, `git diff --stat X Y` is the way to go. Note that the two dot notation here works, but according to the Git Folks, is now being discouraged: `git diff` effectively just replaces the two dots with a space so you might as well do that yourself.

Comment: @MarcoLuzzara Nothing's wrong with your suggestion! Beyond my ignorance (or forgetfulness) that it was even a possibility anyways :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git diff --stat HEAD~10..HEAD
```

> commits that are reachable from r2 excluding those that are reachable from r1 […] can be written as "r1..r2"

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse

Comment: I think the second `HEAD` is superfluous as `HEAD~10..` is implicitly the same revision range expression.

Comment: @Kenny Yes I agree